# Run fstrim from LiveCD

Tags: ssd, lvm, luks, trim

A few years ago I installed Ubuntu 10.04 with LVM + LUKS on a system with SSD, TRIM was not enabled. Now I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on the same SSD.

I have found a guide explaining how to enable TRIM on Ubuntu 12.04 with LVM + LUKS, but before installing the new system, I want to clean out all the "marked for deletion" data generated under Ubuntu 10.04, to make the disk fast as new.

My plan is to boot a Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD and create a new ext4 filesystem on the SSD, then mount the filesystem and run **fstrim** on it. After rebooting the LiveCD I will install the system as normal, and enable TRIM. Can anybody say if this will work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to format the filesystem anyhow, you may just use the `-E discard` switch to `mke2fs` to have it trim the unused portions of the disk.  `e2fsck` also supports the same option so you can trim the fs while checking it rather than formatting it.

```
sudo mke2fs -E discard -T ext4 /dev/sdaX
sudo e2fsck -E discard /dev/sdaX
```